# Laravel - Mutator doesn't seem to work on update

Tags: laravel, mutators

I have the following mutator:

```
public function setFormattedCriteriaAttribute($value)
{
    $this->attributes['formatted_criteria'] = serialize($value);
}
```

When I call the following why doesn't it update the `formatted_criteria` value - note the field is listed in my fillable attributes array ?

```
$jobAlert = JobAlert::findOrFail($id);

$jobAlert->update([
        'frequency' => $request->frequency,
        'criteria'  => $criteria,
        'formatted_criteria' => ['test']
]);
```

Comment: What makes you think it's not updated?

Comment: @patricus I check the results in the database. Other values have updated excpeted the formatted_criteria value which has the mutator

Comment: What do you get from `dd($jobAlert->isFillable('formatted_criteria'));`?

Comment: @patricus i get true. I know its in my fillable array because it saves when I do a create just not when I update.

Comment: @patricus figured it out...I was passing my model in to the method which uses the above code as Jobalert $jobalert instead of JobAlert $jobalert

Answer (score 0):

Be sure formated_criteria in your `$fillable` variable.

**Update**

if you have casts array in your model modify else add.

```
protected $casts = [
        'formatted_criteria'    => 'array',
    ];
```

then update your field as `LONGTEXT` with binary

Comment: it is in my fillable array

Comment: if you keep this field an array, add casts variable and update your column type as longtext binary

Comment: i don't think the casting works on serialized array, it only work on json..I'm having to use an accessor instead to unserialze manually.

Comment: if you are using casts as array or json, you dont need to serialize or unserialize. I am working with json in mysql. Is the best solution for these cases. dont serialize your array, just save it. Delete mutators and accessor for this field

Comment: I have to save it in database as array instead of json becuase when you decode json back to array it doesn't preserve the order of the values and I just need this for display.